# SetMinDate of DatePickerDialog by Calendar value instead of long

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm using this [Example](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/123) to create DatePicker where the method of setMinDate takes the first parameter as Calendar instead of long, I want to execute this method `datePicker.setMinDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis()- 1000);`
How to make the last date as Calendar instead of long without changing the method structure?

The structure of setMinDate in DatePickerDialog is:

```
public void setMinDate(Calendar calendar) {
    mMinDate = calendar;

    if (mDayPickerView != null) {
        mDayPickerView.onChange();
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: instead of long you need date format?

Comment: No, I need Calendar format

Comment: Look to the edition, I post the method structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("Your date"); //2016-02-22


datePicker.setsetMinDate(DateToCalendar(date));


public static Calendar DateToCalendar(Date date){ 
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
return cal;
}
```

Comment: I want to use `calendar.getTimeInMillis()- 1000` to get the previous date, not want to use dateFormate becaus there is no specific format

Comment: Convert String to Date without knowing the format of String.It's not possible.refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707485/how-to-convert-string-to-date-without-knowing-the-format

Comment: also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18893308/how-to-convert-string-to-date-without-knowing-the-format-of-string

Comment: I did it as `Date myDate = new Date(calender.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);
                 datePicker.setMinDate(DateToCalendar(myDate)); `

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.