# Parse string to date using different formats/patterns

Tags: java, string, date, apache-commons

I need to parse a string to a date but have no prior knowledge which pattern the string will be in. This is similar to the question [How to convert String to Date without knowing the format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707485/how-to-convert-string-to-date-without-knowing-the-format).

To solve this I adopted couple of patterns to test the outcome. However, what I am getting is a bit strange.

Example 1:

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateUtils;

    public Date extractDate(String dateStr) {

        String [] datePatterns = {"yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MM-yyyy"};
        Date date = null;

        try {
            date = DateUtils.parseDate(dateStr, datePatterns);
        }
        catch (Exception except) {
                except.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println ("2013-09-30:" + extractDate("2013-09-30") );
        System.out.println ("30-09-2013:" + extractDate("30-09-2013") );

    }
```

This gives:

```
    2013-10-30:Wed Oct 30 00:00:00 EAT 2013
    30-09-2013:Mon Mar 05 00:00:00 EAT 36
```

The result from parsing '30-09-2013' is obviously strange.

Example 2: Here I only switch the pattern

```
        String [] datePatterns = {"dd-MM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd"};
```

This gives:

```
    2013-10-30:Mon Mar 05 00:00:00 EAT 36
    30-09-2013:Mon Sep 30 00:00:00 EAT 2013
```

In example 2 the result from parsing '2013-10-30' is strange.

How can one parse date strings using different formats/patterns so that the resulting dates are correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to use `parseDateStrictly`. When I did this I got the following output:

```
2013-09-30:Mon Sep 30 00:00:00 EDT 2013
30-09-2013:Mon Sep 30 00:00:00 EDT 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be same. Without any prior knowledge of the format you can't parse date.

Few examples of writing a date would be: `DD-MM-YYYY`, `MM-DD-YYYY`, `DD/MM/YYYY`, `MM/DD/YYYY`, `MM/DD/YY`, `DD/MM/YY`. For only these many types of dates can you find any common pattern?

**NO!** Without knowing the format which user enters you can't parse it.

If you come up with pattern matching, a date such as `10-09-2010` which matches with `MM-DD-YYYY` format and `DD-MM-YYYY` format too. Here you will have a problem

Comment: although your assertion is correct, it does not address the error being demonstrated in the question especially as the two formats provided are mutually exclusive.