# Convert date to specific format if I don't know source date format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I want to convert date to a specific format (e.g. en-US MM/dd/yyyy) and I am aware about normal method to parse it.

But in my case I'm unaware about the source date format. Source date format is subject to change as per server environment. It can be en-US or en-GB.

e.g. `DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;`

`'dt'` can be `'27/03/2014'` or `'03/27/2014'`.

How to **convert** the source date to **en-US** format **if I don't know source date format**?

(*string format would be fine - MM/dd/yyyy* e.g. `"03/27/2014"`).

Comment: I'm confused...in your example you already have a datetime object so the "source format" isn't important.  Have I misunderstood?

Comment: I have a DateTime object. True. But according to host environment, it returns date. Converting any date format to MM/dd/yyyy will create problem if it already MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: You can't. If you have 01/02/2014 depending its 1 February or 2 January. You have to know how to read it

Comment: Why would it cause a problem?  A date is a date, it knows internally what day, month and year it is so if you just need to format the DateTime object you can just use .ToString with whatever format you need.

Comment: @DoctorMick it would create problem. Refer wiero's comment.

Comment: @nirav: you're confusing the DateTime object type (which does not have ambiguity) with string representation of date/time (which does have it).

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707485/how-to-convert-string-to-date-without-knowing-the-format

Comment: @DarkWanderer you're right. Just needed to convert it to the specific format using `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`. `Parse` is not working. But 'ToString()' method is surely the way. Thanks for pointing out. e.g. `dt.Tostring("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime.Now.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"); //toString(specify format)
```

try this one

Comment: You're right as I wanted date in string format only. Though I have tried to give more explanation in my Answer. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the source format, there is a chance of getting errors while trying to convert. For example, try converting:

```
05/01/2013
```

A computer wouldn't be able to identify the date in such a case. It could result in two outputs: `05 Jan, 2013` or `01 May, 2013`.

Comment: exactly. I'm facing this issue currently. Even it can throw error if you take date like 15/05/2013.

Comment: @nirav you could send a specific string: `d:05/m:01/y:2013`. Then converting it only needs to be application specific.

Comment: @ReCaptcha in this case I don't know the date. Date is fetched dynamically. Format too is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime result;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(inputString, "dd/MM/yyyy", out result)
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "MM/dd/yyyy");
```

OR

```
DateTime result;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out result)
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your environment will always be the deciding factor, why not just use that?

Try some variation of the following:

```
string yourFormat = ... // Whatever is your default format

if(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-US")
{
     yourFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy";
}
else (if Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name == "en-GB")
{
     yourFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
}

DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, yourFormat, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to convert the source date to en-US format if I don't know source date format?

You need to know the source date format, only then can you convert it to the required date format.

As [wiero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22686580/convert-date-to-specific-format-if-i-dont-know-source-date-format#comment34562799_22686580) has rightly said in the comments "If you have 01/02/2014 depending its 1 February or 2 January. You have to know how to read it".

The default format of the object returned by `DateTime.Now` will be the one specified in your server setting, check the screenshot below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @DarkWanderer's comment in question:

DateTime object has nothing to do with format.

Just needed to convert it to the specific format using `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`.

I was using `Parse()` method to convert but it will not work. B`ToString()` method is surely a way.

This will work: `dt.Tostring("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Thanks @DarkWanderer.