# Returning a date format from an unknown format of date string in java

Tags: java, date-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse any date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)

Suppose we have a string of date in a format (unknown to the user). Examples of acceptable dates that you can receive from a user:

- `yyyy-MM-dd`/`yy-MM-dd`
- `yyyy/MM/dd`/`yy/MM/dd`
- `dd/MM/yyyy`/`dd/MM/yy`
- `MM/dd/yyyy`/`MM/dd/`yy`

Is there a library that accept a date in a string and returns a date format that can be used by `SimpleDateFormat` or Joda Time?

Thanks

Comment: would be interesting to see how a solution could accomodate 09/08/2010 ... how would you know which is month and which is day as both are perfectly acceptable dependent on the user's region

Comment: Did you see the question [Parse any date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3389348/127035) and answers. Not a simple library, but code for your own utility based on pattern matching and then lookup.

Comment: @sdolgy, brilliant question. One should ask the user if that's the correct date it parsed then. I think user should accept which result is correct.

Comment: That question (month or day) is addressed in the other question I linked to also.

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy` is a very uncommon format (I believe it's even not official). Usually `-` is been used as separator for such pattern.

Comment: @BalusC, yes, but `DateFormat` can allow parsing of dates with that specified format. I'm just allowing the possibility someone wants to have it.

Comment: Why would you support an uncommon format?

Comment: Because that's the requirement for this project, I'm afraid. And no, I wasn't there when they debated about this. *cough - Business Analysts*.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution: I will apply each date format on the provided input to get a Date object , then I print the Date object with the same date format. If the input and the output for a date format are the same the date format is a candidate.

Comment: 1) That is a long way and object-initialization and comparison technique that is unecessary.
2) That doesn't solve the issue of whether `03/04/2010` means 3 April or 4th March.

Comment: What you are saying contradicts what you explained in your comment. You said that user should decide about the acceptable result.

Comment: @salman.mirghasemi, fair enough, what I'm saying, if I add 3 April and his solution finds 4 April, his output versus date object comparison check stands valid, there's no way of showing the ambiguous case and notify the user.

Comment: User gets these two: DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY, then chooses one. If you want to make it more user friendly you can show each case in long format by asking this question: "Which one do you mean: 3 April 2010 or 4 March 2010?"

Comment: Pretty much or create a validation that proposes it. Also, the answer doesn't solve the problem of finding an "appropriate" date format based on the date string. It assumes I have a list of date formats defined (which can be long as there are some format that depends on regions and locales, etc.).

Comment: Even in that case, having a list of possible date formats (though that is not complete) can improve the quality of your inference.