# how to change all properties value of type "DateTime" before execution

Tags: c#, datetime, entity-framework-6

My main concern is changing the property value before expression evaluation "not datetime parsing logic" as it's just one case in other case i need to change other property value from x to y

In my application with EntityFramework 6 i have application setting for datetime input format "mm/dd/yyyy" or "dd/mm/yyyy", when a user make a request (querying or saving changes) i want to change all datetime format to mm/dd/yyyy, if setting was mm/dd/yyyy no changes needed, but if setting was dd/mm/yyyy then i need to convert it to mm/dd/yyyy, i need to know where and how to override the property value and achieve the goal, i'm novice in ExpressionVisitors.

This could be the starting point

```
internal class DateTimeInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
        {
            var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
            if (queryCommand != null)
            {
                var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new DateTimeQueryVisitor());
                interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace, queryCommand.DataSpace, newQuery);
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class DateTimeQueryVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
{
    public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
    {
        if (!expression.Target.ElementType.MetadataProperties.Any(mp => mp.Name.GetType() == typeof(DateTime)))
        {
            return base.Visit(expression);
        }

        // here i should do the work for changing the property value
        // Change the expression

        var binding = expression.Bind();
        return binding.Expression; //should be replaced with the modified expression
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: post some code so it will be easy to find out.

Comment: What is "proper format"?

Comment: A `DateTime` doesn't have _any_ implicit format. Sounds like you save your `DateTime` values as a character in your database. That's a bad idea.

Comment: nevermind about the format of datetime or the conversion :), i just need the EntityFrameWork part where i can detect the property of type DateTime and change it's value, for example working with ExpressionVisitors, ParameterVisitor or something like that

Comment: i updated the question with code

Comment: It's still quite unclear what you're asking.  Could you give an example of what you are *actually* trying to achieve?  As-is, this smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  (You've identified expression visitors to solve some problem, and are asking about expression visitors rather than explaining the problem thoroughly.)

Comment: i have application setting for datetime input format "mm/dd/yyyy" or "dd/mm/yyyy", when a user make a request (querying or saving changes) i want to change all datetime format to mm/dd/yyyy, if setting was mm/dd/yyyy no changes needed, but if setting was dd/mm/yyyy then i need to convert it to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: What is the *type* of the expression property you want to change?

Comment: DateTime type, i want to catch the property value and do some logic then replace modify the expression

Comment: I'm completely lost on how this has anything to do with Entity Framework.  A query in EF would be working against a native type, such as `DateTime` - which *has no format*.  A `DateTime` only works with formats when converting to or from *strings*.  It's nonsensical to say you want to change datetime formats in an EF query.

Answer (score 0):

I think its undoable, as a human and not a machine tell me,  what format is this: 02/02/2014? can you guess which is the day and which is the month here?
anyway about `DateTime` parsing you can read some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891777/parsing-the-datetime-format-to-get-format-string):

*EDIT* 
sorry I meant to comment and not answer, if anyone got a problem with this as an answer please do tell I'll remove it.

Comment: never mind about the datetime parsing, could you tell me how to change expression property value before executing the expression in EntityFramework

Answer (score 0):

You can't recognize the formatting of the datetime which user is using that. You should know that the datetime is same as the system's datetime which you set that in your machine's control panel.

The only way that you may get user is using another format is in the exception's of days and months.

For example you want to have `mm/dd/yyyy`so if user used `dd/mm/yyyy` format so it will cause an error after number 12. Then you can change to your special datetime.

Imagine your system set to `mm/dd/yyyy` then you can use these codes :

```
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int month = dt.Month;
            string datetime = dt.ToShortDateString();
            // Do Whatever You Want With The String
            .
            .
            .
            .

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("EORROR. Incorrect DateTime Format ...");
            // Now You Must Change dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy
            .
            .
            .
            .
        }
```

**NOTE** : It won't give you any error if your system's date set to `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Make sure you set your system's format to `mm/dd/yyyy` for working the code.

Comment: thanks for the datetime parsing part, but if you read my question again you will understand that i care more about EntityFrameWork expression property value change

Comment: @MohamedEmaish You can't recognize the format of that until it uses the wrong format of datetime. You can simply give a text to user that ask them to use mm/dd/yyyy format.