# How to compare Dates to see if the formatting is the same for Java

Tags: java, datetime

if i wanted to compare to date objects like date1 and date2, not to check if they are the same date, but to check if the formatting (such as (YY:MM:SS) ) of the dates are the same, how could I go about doing so? I can only seem to find documentation on comparing the actual dates themselves, not the formatting.

for clarification, say i have dates 2017:07:20 and 2016:05:24, i want to see that they are of the same format... hope that helps

Comment: A date has no format: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that, such as format is only to print. Theyr are stored in a big number which allow to have precision from `nanoseconds` to size of `era` and can be represented as many differents ways

A comparison maybe easier to understand : it's the same as `int`, they are stored as `binary` and you can print them in `decimal`, `octal`, `hexa` ...

---

And as `decimal` format is by default for `int, double,...`, it's `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` which is by default for `LocalDateTime`

```
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME));
System.out.println(date);  // will print the same as line 2
```

Comment: Thank you this is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the format from a Date object.

Because the date itself doesn't contain formatting information. Only if you have a date-string you could get the formatting like shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579227/how-to-get-the-given-date-string-formatpattern-in-java).