# Java 1.3 check date string format

Tags: java, pattern-matching, date-format

I have a date which is a String that I get from a database.

```
"12-12-2013" // for example
```

I know how to convert this in java to a date type or change the format in any way I want, there are tones of examples out there. But the thing I can't find is:

I want to be able to find out which pattern the date-string is using I mean if is

```
"dd-MM-yyyy"
//or
"yyyy-MM-dd"
```

or something else.

Is there any example I don't know of or didn't find?

I need this because I have this function to change the string's format:

```
public static String formatMydate(String datestring, String previousformat, String newformat) {
        
            java.util.Date date= null;
            String response = "";
            SimpleDateFormat formater;
            if (datestring.length()>=10){        
                try {                       
                    formater=new SimpleDateFormat(previousformat);
                    date = formater.parse(datestring);
                    response = new SimpleDateFormat(newformat).format(date);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    date=null;
                }
            }

            return response.toString(); 
}
```

But I want to know, before using it, the **"previousformat"** to enter it in the function parameter.

Is there a way to know which pattern a date is using?

**This a duplicate question:**

[Returning a date format from an unknown format of date string in java [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450942/returning-a-date-format-from-an-unknown-format-of-date-string-in-java)

[Parse any date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)

Comment: You are using Java 1.3? I mean seriously?

Comment: @RohitJain Ssssh, you'll scare away all the time travelers from 2000.

Comment: Is 1.3 still available for download?

Comment: I have to use it -.- i know dont ask...

Comment: @devnull [Yes it is.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase13-419413.html)

Comment: @devnull. You want it? Please share with me if you get it.

Comment: @RohitJain I don't want it.  I'd be surprised if it's available.  However, Carsten suggests that it *is* (see link above in the comment).

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple general answer, since some places use `dd-MM-yyyy` and some use `MM-dd-yyyy`. If you only have to distinguish between `dd-MM-yyyy` and `yyyy-MM-dd`, split on the hyphen and count the digits.

Comment: Well i thought about it, i'm just probing the web if there are solutions to this dynamic...if not i have to do it static.

Comment: What do you mean by static/dynamic? You won't know until runtime, right? This is a simple approach that will run on your antique.

Comment: I meant that instead knowing before the string's pattern to insert in the functions parameter i have to place a hardcoded string pattern.

Comment: Please change `mm` to `MM`.