# Is Date.parse() in Java safe to use, even though it is deprecated? If not, is there a viable alternative?

Tags: java, string, date, deprecated, standard-library

I often use [Date.parse(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#parse-java.lang.String-) to parse a date in an unknown format. It seems to work fine for my use cases so far, but I'm wondering why it was deprecated, and whether I should avoid it? The docs just say:

```
As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by DateFormat.parse(String s)
```

However, there's no static parse method in DateFormat, just [an instance method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-), which requires a DateFormat object, which I won't have for an unknown date format.

So, I'm wondering...

- Is there any official statement somewhere from the Java designers about why they chose to deprecate it?
- If this method works fine for my use cases so far, can I rely on this functionality being available in future versions of Java?
- Is there a viable alternative that is not deprecated for parsing a string that is in one of many possible common date formats?

Comment: _It accepts many syntaxes_

Comment: IMHO the whole `Date` *class* should have been deprecated.

Comment: @Bohemian - Is there a good replacement?

Comment: I really don't understand the down-vote here

Comment: @robert see the new `java.time` library, or jodatime library for Java 7.

Comment: How is this "primarily opinion based"? There's a single objective answer. I want to know the reason the Java designers chose to deprecate the API.

Comment: It is deprecated because it was violating "Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)" of Date class and in return brought low cohesion and a bad design.

Answer (score 5):

Date.parse(String) was deprecated because it doesn't internationalize well. [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) objects are preferred.

For personal uses where you know it parses dates well, you probably don't need to avoid it, but you should probably get in the habit of using the more standard options if you're going to be writing more serious date-sensitive code.

Comment: So what's the correct way of parsing a date when you don't know the exact syntax of it and want Java to try its best?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java

Comment: @RobertFraser They didn't deprecated `Date.parse` because they wanted you to use something else, they wanted to deprecate this way of thinking all together. For UIs, use date pickers. For storage, use epoch time. For plaintext input, specify a list of formats. Don't get into a situation where you have to interpret data you don't know the meaning of.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way now to parse a `Date` is to use [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but you need to create an instance first there is no static method anymore.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = format.parse(strDate)
```

`Date` and `Calendar` are simply badly written because they are confusing and error prone, they are meant to totally be replaced by the version of `joda time` that has been included into Java 8, so in anyway you should rely on this method anymore as it will simply be removed very soon.

So if you use Java 8, I highly encourage you to use directly `DateTimeFormat`, if you have a previous version, you should use `SimpleDateFormat` as mentioned above.

What you need to do is:

1. To list all the patterns that you need to support in your code
2. Put them into a collection or an array
3. Then test each of them until the method `parse(String)` doesn't raise a `ParseException`, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4024604/1997376)

Comment: The issue here is that you need a pattern. I'm working with a couple different version control systems that spit out their dates in different ways, both of which Date.parse() handles OK.

Comment: In what way does this answer the OPs question?