# to determine whether the any string is a datetime use java

Tags: java, datetime

give a string ,maybe anything , return if it is datetime .
etc:
 "aaaa"(no) ,"11111" (no) , "2016-11" (yes), "2016-11-11 11:11:11" (yes), "1476010568" (yes).

Waitting  for the advise or code
very thanks!

Comment: just convert it into datetime within try catch ,if exception mean no otherwise yes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java