# Best way to transform date string into an date object

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

What is the best way to transform like `October-2016` into an **Date** Object?

When I try to use `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy").parse("October-2016");`

it throws an exception, because it cannot convert this type of date.

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps your default locale is the problem? Just use `new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy", Locale.US)`

Comment: See also [Parse any date in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3390252/1314743).

Comment: Oh yeah the problem was the locale. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the string October-2016 is containing information related to a language **YOU NEED TO SPECIFY** the Locale in the instance of the **SimpleDateFormat**

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy", Locale.US).parse("October-2016");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String st = "October-2016";
        DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy");
        Date date = format.parse(st);
        System.out.println(date);
```

**Both working same:**

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy").parse("October-2016");
        Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy", Locale.US).parse("October-2016");
        System.out.println(date); 
        System.out.println(date1);
```

Comment: that's the same what I did.

Comment: @SepDev ya i think but its working

Comment: yep it's working because youre locale is standard set to **us** but for me I'm working with a 2 different locales so there is the problem.

Comment: @SepDev but into question you says that its giving error

Comment: yeah because java doesn't know like it's german time format or us

Comment: @SepDev Ya i understand the Local use but you told into question Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM-yyyy").parse("October-2016"); is causing exception

Comment: Yeah like a format exception it could not transform the german date **Oktober** into the date object