# Convert any incoming date format to standard format in Java

Tags: java

Is there any class in Java that could convert incoming dates , which would be in different formats into a standard format .I know SimpleDateFormat does convert date to specific formats, but I need a method that could actually convert all below dates in format which is YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS_inputstring:

### inputs

```
20170112_125645
20170915 137546
09122017:135292
2014012014132390 -- milliseconds in here
```

### output

```
YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS_inputstring
```

We are expecting input date values in multiple formats, which should be converted to  `YYYY-MM-DD_HH:MM:SS_inputstring`
I know this is a very common question , but I couldn't find one specific to my scenario .

Comment: Related: [Parse any date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)

Comment: So you want some magic class??? I don't see how `2014012014132390` can be automagically™ parsed

Comment: *Any* format? No. But there are several utilities available that'll parse from a collection of formats.

Comment: *"Is there any class in Java that could ..."* Yes, there is, when you write it.

Comment: What time of day is `787546` supposed to be? --- Differentiating `ddMMyyyy` and `MMddyyyy`, solely by looking at the value, is impossible, so you can never handle *any* format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know all the possible incoming date formats, you could create a `SimpleDateFormat` instance for each of them. Then for every incoming date string you just run it through the list. If a format won't parse this string it will throw an exception, catch it and move on to the next format, rinse and repeat until you get to one that parses the string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024544/how-to-parse-dates-in-multiple-formats-using-simpledateformat

This also helped

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

No magic way to decipher any random format. But in your case you have easy ways to identify each of the particular formats.

```
DateTimeFormatter f ;
if ( input.contains( "_" ) ) {  // 20170112_125645
    f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd'_'HH:mm:ss" );

} else if ( input.contains( " " ) ) {  // 20170915 137546
    f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMdd' 'HH:mm:ss" );

} else if ( input.contains( ":" ) ) {  // 09122017:135292
    f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "ddMMuuuu':'HH:mm:ss" );

} else if ( input.length() == 16 ) {  // 2014012014132390
    f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmssSS" );

} else {
    … // Handle error condition
    System.out.println( "ERROR - Unexpected input: " + input ) ;

}

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

Of course in real code being called many times often, I would cache those `DateTimeFormatter` instances rather than instantiate each time. Perhaps define an `Enum` if used in various other places in your code base.

Usually I recommend always specifying a `Locale` in the formatter rather than rely implicitly on JVM’s current default. But here I don't think the locale has any effects.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You mentioned `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is one of the troublesome old date-time classes that should be avoided. Now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).