# SoapUI : parse date from string without format

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to parse string into a date.  I'm using soapUI, so it needs to be in groovy.  I know the string is a date.  I don't care about the formatting.  I've tried

```
Date.parse(myDateString)
```

But it seems to want the format of the date.  Is there any way I can parse the date without the code being aware of the format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse any date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389348/parse-any-date-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the format of the string you are parsing into a Date object:

```
 Date date1 = Date.parse('dd-MMM-yyyy', '07-OCT-2018')
```

You say you don't care about the format, but you have to know what format `myDateString` is in, and pass that format to `Date.parse` as first parameter. It can't guess what you are trying to parse :-)